# How to send POST request using HTTPClient with HashMap as one parameter

Tags: java, httpclient

I want to send Post request with many string parameters along with one HashMap object. How to do this?

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;
public class PostRequest {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{


      String url="http://url";      
      PostMethod post=new PostMethod(url);
      post.setParameter("param1","abc");
      post.setParameter("param2","1");
      HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();
      int a = httpclient.executeMethod(post);
      System.out.println("I::::::::::::::::" + a);      
      String postResp = post.getResponseBodyAsString();
      System.out.println("response::::" + postResp);      
    }
}
```

In the above code, I also want to send HashMap object in the request.

```
HashMap hm = new HashMap(); 
hm.put("key","value"); 
//Set this param in URL. 
post.setParameter("paramname",hm);
```

Please help.

Comment: You want to redesign your URL and pass it to HttpClient?

Answer (score 3):

Try to convert your hashmap to JSON string and put in post parameter. After that you can recreate your hashmap from that JSON string.

```
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myMap.put("MyKey", "MyValue");
    String jsonMap = new Gson().toJson(myMap);
    System.out.println(jsonMap);
    /*
     * output :{"MyKey":"MyValue"}
     */

    Map<String, String> myOriginalMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myOriginalMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonMap, HashMap.class);
    System.out.println(myOriginalMap);
    /*
     * output : {MyKey=MyValue}`enter code here`
     */`enter code here`
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly below changes will help you ;

```
PostMethod post=new PostMethod(url);
for (Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    post.setParameter(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: No, I just want to set like this.   HashMap hm = new HashMap(); hm.put("key","value"); Set this param in URL. post.setParameter("paramname",hm);

Comment: as you see in API docs there is no such methods. https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/methods/PostMethod.html

Answer (score 0):

You can put all the strings in a HashMap, and then you can create a JSON object from it. After you can add this JSON to your post as `post.setEntity(se);` where se is StringEntity containing your JSON, like, `StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json.toString());`.

Now, you can pass 'post' to the executeMethod.

Answer (score -2):

You can pass the hashMap as parameter in the method, and then foreach the hashMap while use the PostMethod.

Best Regards,
James